# Using third party providers OAuth2 from both mobile app and HTTP backend

Tags: authentication, mobile, oauth-2.0

I'm somewhat familiar with OAuth2 and how to implement OAUth2 clients and servers but I'm trying to understand if there are patterns to achieve this scenario or if it just doesn't make sense and I should approach it differently.

I'm building a mobile application with a HTTP backend and I want to allow users to authenticate using third party providers like Facebook, Google and the like. My backend server exposes some HTTP APIs which require users to be authenticated, and I would like to let users of the mobile app who have authenticated using those third party providers to access my APIs.

I'm assuming the user authenticates with a third party provider on the mobile app directly, without any interaction with my own backend server. At some point though the user will need to interact with the server and the server will need to know who the user is.

My question is, what should I do on the server side in order to accept requests coming from a user who has authenticated via, say, Facebook in the mobile app? Should I send the access token the user obtained from Facebook? Also, supposing I need to support several providers how I do know whether an access token was issued by Facebook or a different provider?

To be clear I'm not even sure this is a valid flow, perhaps the user should not authenticate to the third party provider directly on the mobile app but maybe there should be some interaction with my backend server at some point, so any advice is very welcome.

Comment: any solution, even am on the same page?